# React-Native: expo-screen-orientation lockAsync() not working on iPad?

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, expo, screen-orientation

I just started a new `React-Native` project using Expo. I'm trying to lock the screen orientation to portrait on any device.
With `ScreenOrientation` from `expo` package, nothing happened. That's why after some research I installed `expo-screen-orientation` package.

You can see my code below (something very simple):

`App.js`

```
import { Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import * as ScreenOrientation from "expo-screen-orientation";

export default function App() {

  ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>OK</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

For information, this code **works** if you want to lock the orientation screen to portrait mode on iOS and Android smartphones (tested on an iPhone 13 and Redmi Note 10).

When it comes to tablets, things start to get complicated. Even with
`ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP);`
the screen still rotates on iPad.

I don't know if the issue comes from the `app.json` file or from the `App.js` file.

`app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "blank",
    "slug": "blank",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android", "web"]
  }
}
```

I don't have any ios/ or android/ folder because I created the project with the following command and settings:

```
> npx create-react-native-app project_name
> How would you like to start : Template from expo/examples
> Pick an example : blank
```

That's why I don't have any pods to install, any settings that I could do through XCode.Here is the tree structure of my project:

```
\
├── .expo/
├── .vscode/
├── node_modules/
├── .gitignore
├── App.js
├── app.json
├── babel.config.json
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

I share you some resources that could be useful to help me :

> [Expo Docs - Screen Orientation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/)

> [expo-screen-orientation package](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-46/packages/expo-screen-orientation)

Comment: this library does not work correctly on ipad, if you are not going to change orientation while the application is running, then block in app.json: "orientation": "portrait" and remove expo-screen-orientation from dependencies and node_modules

Answer (score 0):

it seems this is expected on the iPad since iOS 9 due to the changes enabling split screen functionality...

[expo docs on this](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#warning)

> Warning
> Apple added support for split view mode to iPads in iOS 9. This changed how the screen orientation is handled by the system. To put the matter shortly, for iOS, your iPad is always in landscape mode unless you open two applications side by side. To be able to lock screen orientation using this module you will need to disable support for this feature. For more information about the split view mode, check out the official Apple documentation.